# Android Native GLES 2.0 Blank Screen With MVP Matrix

Tags: android, c++, matrix, opengl-es, projection

I'm drawing a simple quad using gles2.0 in c++. If i draw it with a basic vertex shader there is no problem and this is the result

[image]

```
uniform mat4 u_mvp;
attribute vec4 a_Position;
void main(){
   gl_Position = a_Position;
}
```

if i add MVP matrix

```
gl_Position = u_mvp * a_Position;
```

then there's nothing on screen.

This is the perspective matrix:

```
Matrix4 Matrix4::getPerspective(float angle, float ratio, float near, float far) {
    // angle = 45; ratio = 1.438; near = 1; far = 100
    Matrix4 matrix;

    float top = (float)(near * Math::tangentDegrees(angle / 2.0f));
    float bottom = -top;

    float right = top * ratio;
    float left = -right;

    matrix.m[0] = (2 * near) / (right - left);
    matrix.m[1] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[2] = (right + left) / (right - left);
    matrix.m[3] = 0.0f;

    matrix.m[4] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[5] = (2 * near) / (top - bottom);
    matrix.m[6] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
    matrix.m[7] = 0.0f;

    matrix.m[8] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[9] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[10] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
    matrix.m[11] = -(2 * far * near) / (far - near);

    matrix.m[12] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[13] = 0.0f;
    matrix.m[14] = -1.0f;
    matrix.m[15] = 0.0f;

    return matrix;
}
```

The modelView matrix is obtained as follow:

```
modelView = translation * rotation * scale
mvp = perspective * modelView
```

Each element of this multiplication is obtaied following this example
 http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/
and all of them are initalized at the identity matrix.

With this command i obtain the handle

```
transformUniformHandle = (GLuint)glGetUniformLocation(getProgramId(), "u_mvp");
```

With this command i set the mvp matrix in the shader (tried both GL_FALSE, GL_TRUE)

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformUniformHandle, 1, GL_TRUE, modelViewProjection.m);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL uses column-major storage for matrices, while your projection matrix is set up in row-major order. So you need to transpose the order of the matrix elements:

```
matrix.m[0] = (2 * near) / (right - left);
matrix.m[4] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[8] = (right + left) / (right - left);
matrix.m[12] = 0.0f;

matrix.m[1] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[5] = (2 * near) / (top - bottom);
matrix.m[9] = (top + bottom) / (top - bottom);
matrix.m[13] = 0.0f;

matrix.m[2] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[6] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[10] = -(far + near) / (far - near);
matrix.m[14] = -(2 * far * near) / (far - near);

matrix.m[3] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[7] = 0.0f;
matrix.m[11] = -1.0f;
matrix.m[15] = 0.0f;
```

You tried to transpose the matrix by passing `GL_TRUE` as the 3rd argument here:

```
glUniformMatrix4fv(transformUniformHandle, 1, GL_TRUE, modelViewProjection.m);
```

This is not supported in ES 2.0, the only valid argument value is `GL_FALSE`. You will see a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error when you call `glGetError()` after this. Calling `glGetError()` should be routine if you have any problems with your OpenGL code.

You could keep the matrix row-major if you really wanted to, and change the shader code accordingly by multiplying the vector from the right:

```
gl_Position = a_Position * u_mvp;
```

But it's probably better to just use column-major order for your matrices.

Also, you're not showing your model-view matrix. You'll have to make sure that the view transformation translates the geometry in the negative z-direction, so that it's placed between the near and far planes of the projection transformation your are using.

Answer (score 0):

Given you haven't shown your whole code, I can't be sure, but it could be that you haven't called glUseProgram before calling glUniformMatrix4fv. It might also be that your triangles are clipped out by the projection matrix. Make sure the points are within the clipping ranges. If that doesn't fix it you should get errors from glGetError. This page will explain its use: [OpenGL error checking](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Error)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't post the entire code because there are many objects and it will be very prolix. glUseProgram is called in fact the code works if i don't use the mvp.